# How to prevent my macro from crashing excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am currently working on an excel Userform to generate a report for a lot entered on a given day. The report is stored in a separate word document which contains the results of between 1 and 8 quality samples (number of samples varies by lot). The Userform is meant to load in excel, receive a lot number and date from the user, retrieve samples from that day and lot from a different sheet in the excel workbook and then copy the data into a new word doc based on a custom template. I have inserted the `MsgBox` method into the macro at various points for bug-squashing purposes.

I have hit a snag where once the macro prints the "Copy control variables initialized" message, it empties every value from my worksheet and then freezes. I suspect that the freezing is a result of an error I made in the design of my loop, but that doesn't explain why the spreadsheet's values are removed. I am new to VBA and completely self-taught, so I may just be missing something obvious with my macro, but I would absolutely appreciate any help in putting this together properly.

```
Sub makeReport(lNum As Integer, pDay As Date, name As String)
    'Template Path: \\CORE\Miscellaneous\Quality\Sample Reports\Template\Defect Report.dotm
    'Save path for finished report: \\CORE\Miscellaneous\Quality\Sample Reports
    
    'Initialize word objects and open word
    Dim wApp As Word.Application
    Dim wDoc As Word.Document
    Dim wCell As Word.Cell
    
    MsgBox ("Word Doc Opened")
    
    Set wApp = New Word.Application
    wApp.Visible = True
    Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Add(Template:=("\\CORE\Miscellaneous\Quality\Sample Reports\Template\Defect Report.dotm"), NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)
    
    MsgBox ("Word Objects Initialized")
    
    'Fill in lot number and date at top of report
    With wDoc
        .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<date>>"
        .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
        .Application.Selection = Format(pDay, "mm/dd/yyyy")
        .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
        .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<lot>>"
        .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
        .Application.Selection = lNum
    End With
    
    MsgBox ("Filled in pack date and lot number")
    
    'Initialize excel objects
    Dim wBook As Workbook
    Dim wFunc As WorksheetFunction
    
    Set wFunc = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set wBook = ThisWorkbook
    
    Worksheets("Defect Table").Activate
    Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
    
    MsgBox ("Set Active Sheet to Defect Table")
    
    'Initialize copy control variables
    Dim rowArray(7) As Integer
    Dim tBound As Integer
    Dim cRange As Range
    Dim vRange As Range
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim tHold As Variant
    
    'Counter for do while loop
    count = 0
    
    'Range object containing all used cells
    Set cRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
    
    'First row containing desired lot number
    tHold = Application.Match(lNum, cRange, 0)
    tBound = CInt(tHold)
    
    'Range object containing all unscanned used cells
    Set vRange = cRange.Offset(tBound, 0)
    
    MsgBox ("Copy control variables initialized")
    
    'Finds and stores row numbers of desired samples
    Do While count < 7 And tBound < 3000
        'Adjusts vrange
        vRange = cRange.Offset(tBound, 0)
        
        'Checks if row contains correct date, then copies row number into an array
        If (pDay = vRange.Cells(tBound, 1).Value()) Then
            rowArray(count) = tBound
            count = count + 1
        End If
        
        tBound = tBound + 1
    Loop
    
    count = 0
    
    'Prints out contents of rowArray
    Dim msg As String
    msg = "Rows of samples: "
    
    Do While count < 7
        msg = msg + vbCrLf + CStr(rowArray(count))
        count = count + 1
    Loop
    
    MsgBox (msg)
    
    count = 0
    
    MsgBox ("Appropriate samples found")
    
    'Copies samples over to word doc
    Do While count < 7
    
    Loop
    
    '---MsgBox ("Data copied to Word Doc")
    
    'Saves Document using regular name format for ease of access
    '---wDoc.SaveAs2 Filename:="\\CORE\Miscellaneous\Quality\Sample Reports\" + name, FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault, AddtoRecentFiles:=False
    
    'Zeroes out word/excel objects
    '---Set wDoc = Nothing
    '---Set wApp = Nothing
    '---Set wBook = Nothing
    
    MsgBox ("Report saved and objects zeroed out")
End Sub
```

Comment: `vRange = cRange.Offset(tBound, 0)` is the same as `vRange.Value = cRange.Offset(tBound, 0)` so that's where you're clearing the sheet.  Are you missing a `Set` there?

Comment: I should have put a `Set` there, but it simply lets the program advance slightly farther before freezing and forcing me to close it. It also doesn't copy any data into the array.

Comment: Please read this article about how to debug. It will change your life: http://cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx

Comment: You have `Do While Count < 7: Loop` with no loop content, so it will just loop forever.

Comment: Thanks for the catch on that loop, forgot to fill it in, that helped a bunch.

Comment: In the Defects table, which column has the date and which has the lot number?

Comment: Column A contains date and Column C contains lot number

Comment: By the way, the last `Do...While` Loop was what caused the crash issue, and I have fixed it. Thanks Ted.